# How does the list.append work?

Tags: python

```
 alist = []
 def show(*args, **kwargs):
      alist.append(*args, **kwargs)
      print(alist)


 >>> show('tiger')
 ['tiger']
 >>> show('tiger','cat')
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "<stdin>", line 2, in show
 TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
 >>> show('tiger','cat', {'name':'tom'})
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "<stdin>", line 2, in show
 TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

Since the method append of alist only accepts one argument, why not detect a syntax error on the line `alist.append(*args, **kwargs)` in the definition of the method show?

Comment: because that's not how python works.. There's nothing syntactically wrong with it, the function just doesn't accept more than 1 argument. Try list.extend

Comment: How is the interpreter supposed to know what `alist` will be at the time you call `show`?

Comment: Did you mean to ask why there was no error for `show('tiger')` but there was for `show('tiger','cat')`?

Comment: Another important thing to realize is that, as you demonstrate, there is a way to call `show` without any problems. Why should a function that may work perfectly fine be considered improper syntax?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a syntax error because the syntax is perfectly fine and that function may or may not raise an error depending on how you call it.

The way you're calling it:

```
alist = []
def show(*args, **kwargs):
     alist.append(*args, **kwargs)
     print(alist)

>>> show('tiger')
['tiger']
>>> show('tiger','cat')
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "<stdin>", line 2, in show
 TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

A different way:

```
alist = []
def show(*args, **kwargs):
     alist.append(*args, **kwargs)
     print(alist)

>>> show('tiger')
['tiger', 'tiger']
>>> class L: pass
...
>>> alist = L()
>>> alist.append = print
>>> show('tiger','cat')
tiger cat
<__main__.L object at 0x000000A45DBCC048>
```

Answer (score 1):

Python objects are strongly typed. The names that bind to them are not. Nor are function arguments. Given Python's dynamic nature it would be extremely difficult to statically predict what type a variable at a given source location will be at execution time, so the general rule is that Python doesn't bother trying.

In your specific example, `alist` is not in the local scope. Therefore it can be modified *after* your function definition was executed and the changes will be visible to your function, cf. code snippets below.
So, in accord with the general rule: predicting whether or not `alist` will be a list when you call `.append`? Near-impossible. In particular, the interpreter cannot predict that this will be an error.

Here is some code just to drive home the point that static type checking is by all practical means impossible in Python. It uses non-local variables as in your example.

```
funcs = []
for a in [1, "x", [2]]:
    def b():
        def f():
            print(a)
        return f
    funcs.append(b())

for f in funcs:
    f()
```

Output:

```
[2] # value of a at definition time (of f): 1
[2] # value of a at definition time (of f): 'x'
[2] # value of a at definition time (of f): [2]
```

And similarly for non-global non-local variables:

```
funcs = []
for a in [1, "x", [2]]:
    def b(a):
        def f():
            print(a)
        a = a+a
        return f
    funcs.append(b(a))

for f in funcs:
    f()
```

Output:

```
2       # value of a at definition time (of f): 1
xx      # value of a at definition time (of f): 'x'
[2, 2]  # value of a at definition time (of f): [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a syntax error because it's resolved at runtime. Syntax errors are caught initially during parsing. Things like unmatched brackets, undefined variable names, missing arguments (this is not a missing argument *args means any number of arguments).

`show` has no way of knowing what you'll pass it at runtime and since you are expanding your `args` variable inside `show`, there could be any number of arguments coming in and it's valid syntax! `list.append` takes one argument! One `tuple`, one `list`, one `int`, string, custom class etc. etc. What you are passing it is some number elements **depending** on input. If you remove the `*` it's all dandy as its **one** element e.g. `alist.append(args)`.

All this means that your `show` function is faulty. It is equipped to handle `args` only when its of length 1. If its 0 you also get a TypeError at the point `append` is called. If its more than that its broken, but you wont know until you run it with the bad input.

You could loop over the elements in `args` (and `kwargs`) and add them one by one.

```
alist = []
def show(*args, **kwargs):

    for a in args:
        alist.append(a)
    for kv in kwargs.items():
        alist.append(kv)

    print(alist)
```